# Design patterns for applications with multiple data sources?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I'm currently working on windows form application that needs to operate both offline and online. The idea is that when the device running the application has an internet connection it will fetch from a web service to get its data, however when there is no connection it fetches from a local data source in the form of JSON in the local file system.

I would preferably like to use the Service and Manager design pattern (3-tier). However I am unsure which to give the responsibility to of deciding on the data source to use. Should the managers have access to two different services and each service looks at a different source and understands how to interact with each, or should the services be aware of how to interact with both data sources?

Comment: I would suggest one service that dispatches to one of the two specific implementations based on the current status, so you can keep the business logic separate from the details of persistence, but design questions are very broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the 3 tier pattern with an IoC container, that way you can inject the right DAL Object as the data source of the app, according to the state of the application  - In case it's online, inject an "OnlineDAL" which inherits from IDAL interface, otherwise, inject "OfflineDAL" which also inherits from IDAL interface.

Remember to change the injected class whenever the app goes on/off (with an event listener or something)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I haven't used IoC containers previously so I will read into them.

Comment: I presume that when you refer to DAL you are referring to my service layer?

Comment: I mean the Data Access Layer - the layer which you interact with the Database / Local data source with. I think it's the standard name of this layer according to the 3 tier pattern.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to implement the IoC pattern all by yourself, there are many frameworks helping with that like  [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), etc..

Comment: I'm currently looking at Simple Injector. The only thing that is confusing is where the container should live as it needs to be aware of the DAL. Should this be created at the root Winform?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about this because i usually develop only web apps but i say put it in a global place so every window will have access to it

Comment: Perfect, answers my question. Marked as answered.

Comment: Would you be able to advise how I would switch which DAL I am using with Ninject?

Comment: If you mean how will you determine which instance of DAL is behind the IDAL object (whether it's OnlineDAL or OfflineDAL), the answer is: you don't need to, the IDAL object should provide you methods that manipulating the data or selecting the data regardless of the source type (Local or remote), each IDAL implementation will in turn, take care of implementing IDAL methods in it's own way :)

Comment: But what if you want to apply logic to which is used? For example, if you have no connection then you the other IDAL.

Comment: Well i suggest that you'll start with checking whether  the app is online or not on app start. Then, if its online, surround remote operations with try and catch and if it throws and exception because it went offline, you'll know to switch it to the offlineDal , while its offline, set an interval that checks if the app is back online or not then if it is online, change the to OnlineDAL

Comment: That's where I am confused, you just said "you'll know to switch it to the offlineDal". What I don't understand is how you tell it to do that.

Comment: oh, i miss understood, try something like : Kernel.UnBind() & Kernel.Bind()

Comment: In that case, could I instead have two services in my business logic, an online and offline property each of IDAL.

Comment: Yeah actually it sounds a better idea